# Select Query Using DB

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

**Good morning/evening,**

I have a simple table with a key - value store approach (value is a json field )
Am trying to select all results from a db table where key is `alert_daily_report` and value at least must be one true where value is `{"sms": false, "email": true}`

am using Laravel framework

so far i can say

```
DB::table('my_table')->whereJsonContains('key->alert_daily_report' , confused about the value this is where am stuck )
```

Comment: `->where('alert_daily_report->sms', true)->orWhere('alert_daily_report->email', true)`

Comment: @itachi am afraid alert_daily_report is not the actual column , my actual column is called key , inside this key columns , many values like alert_daily_report , alert_monthly_report etc. then i have another actual column called value , with type json so alert_daily_report (in key column ) has json value {"sms": false, "email": true} ( in value column )